# How to randomly pair data in text file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two files: file(student) where there are 20 students and file(lecturer) where there are 3 lecturers. I want to pair the students and lecturers randomly. For example:

  lecturer(1) = student(2),student(3),student(19)

  lecturer(3) = student(20),student(23)......

  This is the code I have tried. It is not behaving in the manner I had hoped for:

```
import  random
lecturer = open("lecturer.txt", "r")
students = open("students.txt", "r")
spliti = lecturer.read().split("\n")
splitis = students.read().split("\n")
stud = (random.choice(splitis))


for stud in splitis:
   file = open(stud + "txt","w")
    for i in range():
     questinss = random.choice(spliti)
    file.write(lecturer + "\n")
    files = open(students + ",txt", "r")
    file.close()
    lecturer.close()
    students.close()
```

Comment: If you're asking about Python 3, why have you tagged this as `python-2.7`?

Comment: Please read [this](https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking). You should include a [mcve], including what input have you given to the program, and what's the expected and current output.

Comment: Also, [don't tag in title](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles).

Comment: Your indentation in the `for` loop is off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some codes that you can use. Hope it can give you some thoughts.

```
import random

# get the students
with open('student.txt','r') as f:
    students = f.read().split()

# get the lectures
with open('lecture.txt','r') as f:
    lectures = f.read().spilt()

# since you only have three different lectures, we can sequently
# collect them as 0,1,2

reflist = []
for student in students:
    reflist.append( lectures[ random.randrange(3) ] )



# prepare for the print
lecture_student = []
for lecture in lectures:
    count = 0
    ls = []
    for ndx in reflist:
        if lecture == ndx:
            ls.append(students[count])
        count += 1

    lecture_student.append(ls)


# now to file them
with open('pro_lecture_student.txt','wt') as f:
    count = 0
    for lecture in lectures:
        f.write(lecture)
        f.write(': ')
        for student in lecture_student[count]:
            f.write(student)
        f.write('\n\n')
        count += 1
```